# count between cells vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am stuck in a situation I cannot solve.

I have a list showing a customer and his order like illustrated below. Customers i column A and ordernumber in column B

***Customer -     Ordernumber***

- John   -     123
- John   -     456
- John   -     789
- John   -     321
- John   -     654

  -
- Pauline   -     251
- Pauline   -     251
- Pauline   -     251

And so on for 100+ customers.

How do I count the number or orders by each customer and write it in e.g column C? In the example above John has made 5 orders and Pauline 3.

Comment: You could use a formula for this? [Countif()](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countif-HP005209029.aspx)

Comment: But then I would have to make 100+ countif?

Comment: It is up to you. Do you want the count next to each order, then yeah. You could just put it in one cell. If you want vba and they are sorted, I would suggest a do while loop. Otherwise you could still use countif but in vba. Show us what you have so far...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it like this

Sample data

[image]

sort column A by the name ( including column B )

[image]

in column C row 1 add a formula `=COUNTIF(A:A,A1)`

then in row B add this formula `=IF(A2=A1,"",COUNTIF(A:A,A2))`

then drag the second formula all the way own and the result should be

[image]

Comment: Negated the downvote :) Seems like someone did it for retaliating. But personally I would not use this method. I would opt in for Pivot. But for what OP wants, your answer is correct :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout thanks. There is no *preferred* method by the OP so once this questions acures a few more answers at least my answer will demonstrate one way of doing it - may some future visitor find it useful

Comment: @MakeCents no problem. thanks for being honest. As I have already said in the previous comment *let me reword that* - answers should be generalized to avoid users asking the same question over and over because they are just a tiny little different (*localized*). We never know who may come here while searching for a similar issue to be solved and while some people are more skilled than others a detailed answer seems to be always a better one to both groups of users. Also, please remember writing longer, more detailed answers takes longer :)

Answer (score 2):

You could just use a formula:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"John")
```

This would count the number of cells in the range `A:A` that match the string `"John"`.

You can also reference a cell to match on, for example:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,A1)
```

This would count the number of cells in column A that match cell A1 including A1.

Comment: I only showed the countif function with a hardcoded string to demonstrate the function. I figured it would be obvious that wasn't the way to do it. Using a cell reference for the second column is definitely the way to go and the user doesn't need to manually do it for each name.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a function you could also use the Subtotal command (in Office 2010 it's in the Data menu) and select the Count function in the "Use function" field and the **Ordernumber** in the "Add subtotal to" list.

For the Subtotal command to work you have to have columns labels.
Note that this will insert new lines instead of putting the totals in a new column which may or not be acceptable to you.

See [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/insert-subtotals-in-a-list-of-data-in-a-worksheet-HP010342620.aspx) for the Office online help regarding the command.